# The PATCH method is not supported for this route

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

i can't find the problem, i want to update the data to database, but i get Patch method is not support. i can't find the problem, i check from book refrence have not different, but in this case can't run for update.

this is my web.php

```
Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::get('laravel/data', 'LaravelController@listData')->name('laravel.data');
Route::resource('laravel', 'LaravelController');
```

this my controller

```
/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $laravel = Laravel::find($id);
    $laravel = $request['id'];
    $laravel->tanggal_pemasangan = $request['tanggal'];
    $laravel->pitstop = $request['pitstop'];
    $laravel->merk_ban = $request['merk_ban'];
    $laravel->no_series_ban = $request['series_ban'];
    $laravel->jenis_mobil = $request['jenis_mobil'];
    $laravel->plat_nomor = $request['plat_mobil'];
    $laravel->posisi_ban = $request['posisi_ban'];
    $laravel->status = $request['status'];
    $laravel->update();
}
```

my form.blade

```
<form class="form-horizontal" data-toggle="validator" method="POST">
        @method('POST')
        @csrf
```

and my ajax

```
$('#modal-form form').validator().on('submit', function(e){
            if(!e.isDefaultPrevented()){
                var id = $('#id').val();
                if(save_method == "add") url = "{{ route('laravel.store') }}"
                else url = "laravel/"+id;
                $.ajax({
                    url : url,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $('#modal-form form').serializa(),
                    success : function(data){
                        $('#modal-form form').modal('hide');
                        table.ajax.reload();
                    },
                    error: function(){
                        alert("Tidak dapat menyimpan data!");
                    }
                });
                return false;
            }
        });
function editForm(id){
        save_method = "edit";
        $('input[name = _method]').val('PATCH');
        $('#modal-form form')[0].reset();
        $.ajax({
            url : "laravel/"+id+"/edit",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data){
                $('#modal-form').modal('show');
                $('.modal-title').text('Edit Data');

                $('#id').val(data.id);
                $('#tanggal').val(data.tanggal_pemasangan);
                $('#pitstop').val(data.pitstop);
                $('#merk_ban').val(data.merk_ban);
                $('#series_ban').val(data.no_series_ban);
                $('#jenis_mobil').val(data.jenis_mobil);
                $('#plat_mobil').val(data.plat_nomor);
                $('#posisi_ban').val(data.posisi_ban);
                $('#status').val(data.status);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("Tidak dapat menampilkan data!");
            }
        });
    }
```

every time i want to do update, always give me error 405 this method is not support

Comment: try again after `php artisan view:clear` and `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: @sta it's not work, and still the same result

Answer (score 1):

Verify that your server supports the HTTP request: "PUT".

In your blade.php file add the `@method('put')` inside the form.

```
<form method="POST">
        @method('PUT')
        @csrf
        ...
</form>
```

Considering that resource type controllers generate the routes for you, perhaps you should use the `php artisan route:list` command to check the update route parameters.

Some examples of generated routes for resource type controllers, [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller).

Now maybe it can be a route hierarchy problem, try changing the order of your routes like this.

```
Route::resource('laravel', 'LaravelController');
Route::get('laravel/data', 'LaravelController@listData')->name('laravel.data');
```

Comment: If i changing the order of route, my route will ignore laravel.data. i think the problem in my button submit function, cause i check my network, its not request to laravel/id, but request to laravel only without the id

Comment: In this case, perhaps, you should consider renaming your route to avoid such complications.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::resource() #update method uses PATCH|PUT verb instead of POST
```

In your case you use `POST` method so the request will be not compatible, You need to use `PATCH` or `PUT` instead of `POST` in your type in ajax or in the form if necessary

Comment: but, in the different project, i use the same code and method not having a problem